# how can i access properties of an object

Tags: javascript, html, object, properties, console

i have an array of objects and i want to return the 'message' property of each of the objects.

i got the objects by calling my own oModel.oData which i created. now that i have these 5 objects how can i get the "message" property from these 5?

also, is there a way to count the number of objects i have in total? e.g sum of oModel.oData objects?

*note the objects are inside an array.

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use *.length* to count your objects inside an array.

```
 YourArray.length
```

this will return the numbers of element *(in your case the object)* inside the array.

As for the message you will need to loop each object inside of your array. you can easily do that using **JQuery** library https://jquery.com/

It will look like this

```
$(function(){
  $.each(YourArray,function(i){
    console.log(YourArray[i].message);
  });
});
```

Or in javascript

```
for (var i = 0; i < YourArray.length; i++) {
  console.log(YourArray[i].details);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's an array, you can simply do `array.length` to get the total number of objects.

As for getting the message from each of them, you'd simply have to loop over the array like :

`array.forEach(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj.message)
});`

Let me know if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1:**

```
for (var i = 0; i < oModel.oData.length; i++) {
  console.log(oModel.oData[i].message);
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
(oModel.oData).forEach(function (obj) {
  console.log(obj.message);
});
```

to get your objects length:

```
var _len = oModel.oData.length;
console.log(_len);
```

You can read more about arrays [here.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)